# Which type of chart is this in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I am using chart.js and Django in my project to show data in a chart.
I need different types of chart. But In chart.js documentation, I am unable to find the type of chart which I have attached.

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar', # here shows ber type
    data: data,
});
```

Which type will I write to show the chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of chart is called [**horizontal bar**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) chart. So, you should set type ...

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: data,
    options: {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. How many types of bar can I show? Do you provide me a list except  doccumentation bar type?

Comment: run - `console.log(Chart.controllers)` and you'll get all the chart types.